# Flexslider Carousel do not display images on slider

Tags: jquery, flexslider

Flexslider Carousel do not display images on slider but when I inspect in browser it display images.

**HTML Code**

```
<div class="flexslider">
  <ul class="slides">
    <li>
      <img src="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_lemon.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_caramel.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_lemon.jpg" />
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**jQuery Code**

```
$(window).load(function() {
  $('.flexslider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide"
  }); 
});
```

**[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xf5tg469/1/)**

Comment: There is an error in the console, at least on your `jsFiddle`: _Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/plain: "http://flexslider.woothemes.com/js/modernizr.js"._

Comment: I do not understand what you say but How I can fixed that?

Comment: Also you're not loading the `flexslider` script, just its stylesheet.

Comment: downvoter please comment?????????????

Comment: Just by adding the `flexslider` library script, it started to work like magic? http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/xf5tg469/2/

Comment: How were you expecting it to work without the library itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry! I forgot to import `jquery.flexslider.js` library and I resolve my problem to adding this library and it working fine for me.

**[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xf5tg469/3/)**

Answer (score 2):

Add this css and try again

```
.flexslider .slides > li{
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: This fixed my problem. Thanks.